# Connection pooling clarification

Tags: jdbc, connection-pooling

I am using connection pooling with the following values:

Minimum connections=1, purge policy=entire pool, age timeout= 0.

I have the following queries:

1. If I have 5 connections and the connections are to be purged then all 5 of them will be purged or 1 connection will still be maintained (since minimum connection is set to 1)?
2. If minimum connection is to be maintained then which connection will be selected i.e newest,oldest or any other connewction will be used?
3. Is there any way in which I can explicitly return a connection logically back to the pool (say using statements like connection.close() or using similar statements)?
4. Is there a way to find out the type of connection pooling I am using?

Comment: "Is there a way to find out the type of connection pooling I am using?" - You need to tell *us* that before we can answer the rest.

Comment: Can you just guide me how can I do that

Answer (score 1):

1. Purge policy *usually* relates to relates to stale connections. "purge pool" means when
   a broken connection is detected, purge the pool, not just the broken
   connnection. If all connections were to be purged, it would empty the pool, then create 1 new one. Anyone wait on a connection would block until a connection was created in the pool.
2. No one on stack overflow could probably answer this
   question... But does it really matter? Why would you ever want to
   "know" this?
3. Yes, end your current transaction by returning from
   your method and let it commit or rollback. If you're using XA
   (global) transactions, you'll have to be done with the global
   transaction.
4. Define "type"? What are our options?

EDIT 4:
If you're in an application container (which it sounds like you are) you don't get to define a "Type." The container provides it's own implementation. For instance, IBM Websphere provides an IBM pooling implementation proprietary to IBM. (It also happens to suck)

Comment: 3.Yes, end your current transaction by returning from your method and let it commit or rollback. If you're using XA (global) transactions, you'll have to be done with the global transaction.

Comment: Refering to the third point.I am only firing a select query on to the database.Even then do I need to commit/rollback or it will be done automatically?

Comment: If you participate in a global transaction, even with a select statement, you could hold a lock on the rows used.